# EF inheritance failing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: Class Diagram]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqCwa.png

I have this EF model. Service is declared as an abstract class, and Claim and Assistance inherits from it. However, the designer is complaining about Service.ServiceId not been mapped:  "Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 205:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Service.IdService) of the EntitySet Service."

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for the records if it can help someone else, I found the answer in this tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293.aspx

The key is deleting the relationship between the base table and the derived ones from the model, remove the PK from the derived classes in the model and setting the inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

`ServiceId` in Assistance and in Claim must be a key. Try to update your EDMX from your Database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little odd that you are deriving `Assistance` and `Claim` from `Service`, yet also have a one-to-many relationship.

If `Claim` and `Assistance` share properties with `Service`, yet also need a one-to-many relationship with `Service`, I would suggest making `Service` not abstract, and creating a separate base class for them all to inherit from